# Laravel when redirect change div class

Tags: html, laravel, redirect

For example if we have

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
```

and we have contact form in **tab2**.
If contact form got fail and `return redirect->back()` or refresh this page. Can change **tab** class to **tab active** active the tab2?

i mean, after redirecting it must be like this:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab">
<div id="tab2" class="tab active">
```

What should i add the controller?

i don't know is possible to make something like that:

```
return redirect()->route('contact_page')->with([some html codes]);
```

i can't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Something like this.

In controller

return redirect()->route('contact_page')->with('tab2_active', true);

In view

<div id="tab1" class="tab {{ !session('tab2_active') ? 'active', null }} "> 
<div id="tab2" class="tab {{ session('tab2_active') ? 'active', null }}">
```

Try that one.